# Using "now" from a character's POV

Tags: creative-writing, style, pov

The story is written in 3rd person POV, close. But I feel like the very last end feels jarring.

> He trailed his hand along the railing as he climbed the stairs so he could catch himself if he fainted or if his legs gave out from under him. He was so close to having his chance to fight for the title, it wouldn’t do at all if he fell and busted his face open. He couldn’t afford an injury. Not now.

Is it just me or is it objectively jarring? Is it that the POV is too far out to tack on the "Not now" ending?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if "Not now" changes the depth of the POV, but I would argue that both of those last two sentences are repeating the sentence before it. If it's so close to his chance, we know he can't afford an injury right now. There's a few other instances of repetition I might eliminate that make for more concise narration.

> so he could catch himself if he fainted or if his legs gave out from
> under him.

He's going to fall with either of those events. You can use either of those alone to convey the full consequence.

> it wouldn’t do at all if he fell and busted his face open

If he falls, is it expected he'll bust his face open? If he busts his face open, is it easily assumed that it's from a fall?

If we squeeze out some of those repetitions, we could get something like this that still maintains the deep POV.

> He trailed his hand along the railing as he climbed the stairs so he
> could catch himself if his legs gave out from under
> him. He was too close to fighting for the title to ruin his chances by busting his face open.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel the very last end is jarring, drop it.

This is purely a Question of style, which means either all that matters is what you feel, or you might like to join a week(end) seminar for writers where you could explore the topic in useful detail.

What's 3rd person POV, "close," please?

What might make this "objectively…" rather than just "jarring"?

Comment: I always feel a bit weird when I'm in POV and I read things like 'tonight' or 'now' or 'yesterday.' I meant objective in the sense that other persons who aren't attached to the story might just read the sentence and find it structurally wrong.